# How to call the right function based on only runtime typeIDs at runtime?

Tags: c++, entity-framework, templates

I have a problem where I can add and remove objects of different types to another type, and I need to be able to know how to build, destroy, copy etc these objects from a typeID at runtime:

```
#include <vector>

int ComponentTypeCounter = 0;

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> components; // Each component type has a vector

struct Entity
{
    template <typename T>
    void addComponent()
    {
        static int componentTypeID = ComponentTypeCounter++;
        // Pair is a: componentIDType and b: position in vector
        std::pair<int, int> compInfo{ componentTypeID, components<T>.size() };
        this->ownedComponents.push_back(compInfo);
        
        components<T>.push_back(T()); 
        
    }
    ~Entity()
    {
        for (auto& comp : this->ownedComponents)
        {
            // All we have here to remove from the right components vector is the componentTypeID
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ownedComponents;
};


struct VelocityComponent {};
struct PositionComponent{};
struct SoundComponent {};
struct IsAnimalComponent { ~IsAnimalComponent() { std::cout << "IsAnimalComponent being destroyed\n"; } };


int main()
{
    Entity ent1;
    ent1.addComponent<SoundComponent>();
    ent1.addComponent<PositionComponent>();
    ent1.addComponent<VelocityComponent>();
    
    //ent1.removeComponent<VelocityComponent>(); // Removing a known type at compile time isn't a problem

    {
        Entity ent2;
        ent2.addComponent<PositionComponent>();
        ent2.addComponent<IsAnimalComponent>();
    }
        // On destruction all ent2 knows is that it has a (1) component, and a(3) component
        // It cannot reach the right vector to remove the component because it only has the //componentTypeID
        // at runtime.
}
```

Comment: BTW, keeping position in vector is also problematic, as removal should impact the other entity.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, thank you, it's just for example.

Comment: Instead of `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> ownedComponents;`, you might have `std::vector<std::function<void()>> onDestroyed;`.

Comment: `std::map<int, std::variant<tag<Component1>, tag<Component2>, tag<Component3>, ..>>` might also be helpful.

Comment: @Jarod42 Whats the tag?

Comment: Something like: `template <typename> struct tag{};`, just something which hold the type.